# Make SwipeRefreshLayout child view height wrap content

Tags: android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

I have a scrollable view within a SwipeRefreshLayout and want its horizontal scoll be placed right under the data.

But according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) the SwipeRefreshLayout can only support one direct child and the child's both width and height are forced to match the parent.

which results in the view always match the parent and horizontal scroll placed at the bottom of the parent.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I've tried putting the view inside a LinearLayout like below and it made wrap_content work correctly, but now when you scroll the view down, the SwipeRefreshLayout refresh is triggered instead of scroll.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Any ideas on how to make the child view height wrap content and without breaking the scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Does this way help ?

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipetorefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/base_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_data"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: No, if the child is scrollable, the scroll won't work properly. It is described in the question.

Comment: @yaugenka I made some changes to the code. I added a recyclerview as a child here. Can you try this and tell me whether this worked for you

Comment: Nope. `SwipeRefreshLayout`'s height needs to be `match_parent` whereas scrollable child's - `match_content`.

Comment: @yaugenka ok fine. Let me see again if I can find something more